# How to write another field from a wizard Odoo 11

Tags: python, xml, odoo-11

I want to change a field value from wizard. The field itself is not within wizard. Here is the code:

```
class TestMapWizard(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'test.testmapwizard'
_description = 'Map Wizard'

name = fields.Char(string='Coordinates', required=True)

@api.onchange("name")
def _change_coordinates(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.name:
            ids = self.env["test.map"].search([('name', '=', record.name)])
            if ids:
                ids.write({'name': self.name})
```

Comment: How do you open the wizard form?

Comment: With a type action button.

Comment: Pass record id in context and use it in `TestMapWizard` to update the record.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your ***active_id*** from the button through ***context***

Example: In your XML file

```
<button name="%(your_wizard_act_window_id)d" type="action" context="{'default_active_id':active_id}" string="Your String"/>
```

In your Python(wizard code):

```
@api.onchange("name")
def _change_coordinates(self):
    for record in self:
        if self.env.context.get('default_active_id'):
           active_id = self.env.context.get('default_active_id')
        if record.name:
            ids = self.env["test.map"].browse(active_id)
            for id in ids:
                id.write({'name': self.name})
    return True
```